# Xslt expression [.=

Tags: xslt

I have here a small XSLT code, but I don't understand one of the expressions and also one of my added values doesn't work.

Here is what i have:

```
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contentclass[. = 'STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary'] and {imageurl/@imageurldescription} = 'Web Page'">
        <div class="srch-Icon" id="{concat($currentId,'_Icon')}">
            <img align="absmiddle" src="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" border="0" alt="Document Library" />
        </div>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
         <div class="srch-Icon" id="{concat($currentId,'_Icon')}">
          <img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
        </div>   
      </xsl:otherwise>
```

Basically as you see, what does this expression means => "[.="?

And secondly this   doenst work, anyone know why?

```
{imageurl/@imageurldescription} = 'Web Page'
```

Why the problem can exist?
The value exists 100% as in default call it works (in otherwise i do get value there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ }` around an expression in an attribute on a normal element will make the XSLT engine evaluate it, instead of treat it as text. In most attributes on control-elements (`<xsl:...`), the curly braces are not needed, and there will be a syntax error if you include them.

The `contentclass[. = 'STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary']` part means: Match all child `contentclass` elements whenever their content is `"STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary"`. It is equivalent to: `contentclass = 'STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary'`

**Read more:**

- [XSLT 1.0: Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)

Comment: writing it like that imageurl/@imageurldescription = 'Web Page' still doesnt evalute :( why?

Comment: @Alnedru Could you paste the XML you are testing with? It would make it much easier to diagnose the problem.